# Splunk alert if amount of logs for today 10% grater than average for the past three days per service

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I would like to create an alert that is triggered when the number of logs for today 10% greater than average for the past three days per service.

For one specific service I can use next

```
index="some-index" AND "ctx.endpointname"="service-name" earliest=-3d@d |
timechart span=1d count |
timewrap d series=short |
eval threshold=(((s1+s2+s3)/3)+(((s1+s2+s3)/3)*0.1))'
```

But when I adding `by ctx.endpointname`

```
index="some-index" AND "ctx.endpointname"=* earliest=-3d@d |
timechart span=1d count by ctx.endpointname|
timewrap d series=short |
eval threshold=(((s1+s2+s3)/3)+(((s1+s2+s3)/3)*0.1))'
```

the result fields names:

```
service-name_s0
service-name_s1
service-name_s2
service-name_s3
```

and I can't calculate the threshold as I don't know how to refer to this field for each service

Answer (score 0):

index="some-index" AND "ctx.endpointname"="service-name" earliest=-3d@d latest=@d | addinfo | eval orig_time = strftime(_time, "%H:%M:%S")| eval min_time = info_min_time | bucket span=1440m info_min_time | eval offset = min_time - info_min_time | eval _time=_time-offset| bucket span=1440m _time | eval _time=_time+offset | eval min_time = strftime(min_time, "%H:%M:%S") | eval info_min_time = strftime(info_min_time, "%H:%M:%S")| bucket _time span=1440m | stats count as current_count by _time| autoregress current_count as previous_count | eval total_count=(current_count+previous_count)|streamstats count as row| eval change=(current_count-previous_count) | eval ChangePercent=(change/total_count)*100 |fields _time, current_count, previous_count, change, ChangePercent,row |  where current_count>x AND ChangePercent>10 AND row=2

Please use above query and change the Current count you will get your desired results.

Comment: Thank you. It works :-). But the main problem for me is to do the same but for all services. When "ctx.endpointname"=*. I've changed the code in the body.
service-1-current, service-1-previous, service-1-change ... service-x-current...